# How to update a label in Kivy every second

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

**Hello developers, greetings from Austria**

Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to update a label in the Kivy Interface permanently.

*Situation: For my diploma thesis I have to develop a GUI for a driving Robot. In this User Interface, there's a Label which should display the current velocity of the robot. The Velocity gets measured by a Raspberry PI and sent over to the User Interface using a socket*

I've managed to change the label, but only if the joystick in the Interfaces gets moved.

```
def _update_joystick_output(self, instance, pad):   #send joystick data
    global driving_assistant
    global connection_check_rpi
    global joystick_data
    global m
    m = str(instance.magnitude)[0:5]
    a = str(instance.angle)[0:5]
    joystick_data=m+" "+a
    self.root.update_label(m)  #This command updates the label in the Interface
    if connection_check_rpi == True:
        if(len(joystick_data) <= 12):
            s1.send(str.encode(joystick_data))
```

I've already tried to program a Thread which updates the Label automatically every half second the same way shown above, but it does not work in any case.

```
class Velocity(threading.Thread):
def run(self):
    global vel
    global s1
    global connection_check_rpi

    self.root = Interface()

    while True:
        if connection_check_rpi == True:

            try:
                rpm_data = s1.recv(1024)
                vel = rpm_data.decode('utf-8')
                self.root.update_label
            except:
                break
        else:
            break
```

Here is the complete code (don't mind the indents)

```py
import threading
import time
import socket

from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.garden.joystick import Joystick
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (1,  1,  1,  1)

global connection_check_rpi
global connection_check_cam
global driving_assistant
global vel
global m
global cruise_control
global tempHelper
global test_check

vel = 0
tempHelper = 0

driving_assistant=False
cruise_control = False
test_check=False
connection_check_rpi=False
connection_check_cam=False

presentation = Builder.load_string(        #place all objects in GUI
"""
#File name: accept_SSCc.py
#: import Joystick kivy.garden.joystick.Joystick

<Interface>:
    Image:
        id: pic
        source:'c:/python/bg.png'
        pos: root.width/2-60, root.height/2-50
    Label:
        id: con1
        text: '[color=010203]'+root.connection1+'[/color]'
        pos: root.width/2-60, -root.height/2+40
        markup: True
    Label:
        id: con2
        text: '[color=010203]'+root.connection2+'[/color]'
        pos: root.width/2-67, -root.height/2+15
        markup: True
    Label:
        id: auto
        text: '[size=20][color='+root.colorauto+']'+root.auto_label+'[/color][/size]'
        pos: 0, -root.height/2+70
        markup: True
    Label:
        id: rpm
        text: '[size=40][color=0039FF]'+root.rpm+'[/color][/size]'
        pos: 0, -root.height/2+120
        markup: True
    Label:
        id: cc
        text: '[size=20][color='+root.colorcc+']'+root.cc_label+'[/color][/size]'
        pos: 0, -root.height/2+50
        markup: True
    Label:
        id: value
        text: '[size=20][color=000000]'+root.cc_value+'[/color][/size]'
        pos: root.width/2-170, -root.height/2+200
        markup: True
    Button:
        text: "ANBS"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 175, 120
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2-320, 2*root.height/7-110
        on_press: root.button_auto()
    Button:
        text: "CC"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 180, 60
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2+140, 2*root.height/7-50
        on_press: root.button_cc()
    Button:
        text: "+"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 90, 60
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2+140, 2*root.height/7-110
        on_press: root.button_faster()
    Button:
        text: "-"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 90, 60
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2+230, 2*root.height/7-110
        on_press: root.button_slower()
    Button:
        text: "sh"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 70
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2+120, 1.7*root.height/2-10
        on_press: root.button_sh()
    Button:
        text: "dc"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 70
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2-100, 1.7*root.height/2-10
        on_press: root.button_dc()
    Button:
        text: "con"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 200, 70
        color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        background_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        pos: root.width/2-320, 1.7*root.height/2-10
        on_press: root.button_con()
    Joystick:
        outer_size: 0.5
        inner_size: 0.25
        pad_size:   0.5
        outer_line_width: 0.01
        inner_line_width: 0.01
        pad_line_width:   0.01
        outer_background_color: (0.5, 0, 0, 1)
        outer_line_color:       (0, 0, 0, 1)
        inner_background_color: (0.2,  0,  0, 1)
        inner_line_color:       (0,  0,  0,  1)
        pad_background_color:   (0,  0,  0,  0.96)
        pad_line_color:         (1,  0,  0,  0.5)
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        pos: root.width/4, root.height/4+20
 """)

class Interface(FloatLayout):
    connection1=StringProperty()
    connection2=StringProperty()
    auto_label=StringProperty()
    cc_label = StringProperty()
    rpm = StringProperty()
    colorcc = StringProperty()
    colorauto = StringProperty()
    cc_value = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global vel
        super(Interface, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.connection1 = "              rpi: dc"
        self.connection2 = "               cam: dc"
        self.auto_label = "Notbremssystem off"
        self.cc_label = "CruiseControl off"
        self.stop_platzhalter = ""
        self.rpm = str(vel)+" km/h"
        self.colorauto = "FF0000"
        self.colorcc = "FF0000"
        self.cc_value = "Control: None"

    def button_test(self, *args):
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global command
        global test_check
        global s1
        global joystick_data

        if connection_check_rpi == True:
            if test_check==False:
                test_check = True
                command="test_on"
                s1.send(str.encode(command))
                joystick_data = "1.0 90"
                print(joystick_data)
                s1.send(str.encode(joystick_data))
            elif test_check==True:
                test_check=False
                command="test_off"
                s1.send(str.encode(command))
                joystick_data = "0.0 90"
                print(joystick_data)
                s1.send(str.encode(joystick_data))


    def button_cc(self, *args):
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global command
        global cruise_control
        global s1
        global joystick_data
        global tempHelper

        if connection_check_rpi == True: #gehört noch auf true geändert
            if cruise_control == False:

                cruise_control = True
                command="cc_on"
                s1.send(str.encode(command))

                tempHelper = 6
                print(tempHelper)

                self.cc_label = "CruiseControl on"
                self.colorcc = "009910"
                self.cc_value = "Control: %i km/h" % tempHelper

            elif cruise_control == True:

                cruise_control = False
                command="cc_off"
                s1.send(str.encode(command))

                tempHelper = 0
                print(tempHelper)

                self.cc_label = "CruiseControl off"
                self.colorcc = "FF0000"
                self.cc_value = "Control: None"

    def button_faster(self, *args):
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global cruise_control
        global command
        global s1
        global joystick_data
        global tempHelper

        if connection_check_rpi == True and cruise_control == True: #auf True
            if tempHelper < 10.5:
                tempHelper += 1
                print(tempHelper)
                command="cc_faster"
                s1.send(str.encode(command))
                self.cc_value = "Control: %i km/h" % tempHelper


    def button_slower(self, *args):
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global cruise_control
        global command
        global s1
        global joystick_data
        global tempHelper

        if connection_check_rpi == True and cruise_control == True: #auf True
            if tempHelper > 4.5:
                tempHelper -= 1
                print(tempHelper)
                command="cc_slower"
                s1.send(str.encode(command))
                self.cc_value = "Control: %i km/h" % tempHelper


    def button_sh(*args):               #shut servers down
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global s1
        global s2
        command="sh"
        if connection_check_rpi == True:
            s1.send(str.encode(command))
            s1.close()
        if connection_check_cam == True:
            s2.send(str.encode(command))
            s2.close()
        Smart3DControl().stop()

    def button_dc(self, *args):         #disconnect from server
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global s1
        global s2
        command="dc"
        if connection_check_rpi == True:
            s1.send(str.encode(command))
            s1.close()
            connection_check_rpi=False
        if connection_check_cam == True:
            s2.send(str.encode(command))
            s2.close()
            connection_check_cam=False
        self.connection1 = "              rpi: dc"
        self.connection2 = "               cam: dc"
        print("disconnected")

    def button_auto(self, *args):       #de/activate driving assistant
        global s1
        global s2
        print("auto")
        command="auto"
        if connection_check_rpi == True and connection_check_cam == True:
            s1.send(str.encode(command))
            s2.send(str.encode(command))
            global driving_assistant
            if driving_assistant == False:
                driving_assistant = True
                self.auto_label = "Fahrassistent on"
                self.colorauto = "009910"
            elif driving_assistant == True:
                self.auto_label = "Fahrassistent off"
                self.colorauto = "FF0000"
                driving_assistant = False

    def button_con(self, *args):        #connect to servers
        global connection_check_rpi
        global connection_check_cam
        global s1
        global s2
        print("con")

        host1 = '192.168.42.1'  # raspberry
        port1 = 5560

        host2 = '192.168.42.2'  # camera
        port2 = 5568
        try:

            if connection_check_rpi == False:
                s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s1.connect((host1, port1))
                print(str(s1))
                self.connection1=str("rpi: "+host1)

                print("connected to rpi")
                connection_check_rpi=True
                print(s1)
                thread = Velocity()
                thread.start()
                thread1 = Ausgabe()
                thread1.start()

            if connection_check_cam == False:
                s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s2.connect((host2, port2))
                self.connection2=str("cam: "+host2)

                print("connected to camera")
                connection_check_cam=True
                print(s2)
        except:
            pass

    def update_label(self, m, *args):
        global vel
        global cruise_control
        global s1
        global test_check

        self.cc_label = "CruiseControl off"
        self.colorcc = "FF0000"
        self.cc_value = "Control: None"

        if cruise_control == True:
            command="cc_off"
            s1.send(str.encode(command))
        cruise_control = False

        if test_check == True:
            command="test_off"
            s1.send(str.encode(command))
        test_check = False

        if str(vel)[1:2] is ".":
            vel = str(vel)[:4]
        else:
            vel = str(vel)[:5]
        #print(m)
        if m == 0:
            self.rpm = "0 km/h"
        else:
            self.rpm = str(vel)+" km/h"
        #print(self.rpm)


class Smart3DControl(App):
    global vel
    global m

    def build(self):
        self.root = Interface()
        joysticks = self.get_joystick(self.root)   #assign joystick to variable

        for joystick in joysticks:
            joystick.bind(pad=self._update_joystick_output) #bind function to joystick

    def get_joystick(self, parent):
        joysticks = []
        if isinstance(parent, Joystick):
            joysticks.append(parent)
        elif hasattr(parent, 'children'):
            for child in parent.children:
                joysticks.extend(self.get_joystick(child))
        return joysticks

    def _update_joystick_output(self, instance, pad):   #send joystick data
        global driving_assistant
        global connection_check_rpi
        global joystick_data
        global m
        m = str(instance.magnitude)[0:5]
        a = str(instance.angle)[0:5]
        joystick_data=m+" "+a
        #print(joystick_data)
        self.root.update_label(m)
        if connection_check_rpi == True:
            if(len(joystick_data) <= 12):
                s1.send(str.encode(joystick_data))

class Velocity(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global vel
        global s1
        global connection_check_rpi

        self.root = Interface()

        while True:
            if connection_check_rpi == True:

                try:
                    rpm_data = s1.recv(1024)
                    vel = rpm_data.decode('utf-8')
                    self.root.update_label
                except:
                    break
            else:
                break

Smart3DControl().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by using the `Clock` to call your callback every e.g. 250ms.
Add this to your `build` method:

```py
    def build(self):
        self.root = Interface()
        joysticks = self.get_joystick(self.root)   #assign joystick to variable

        for joystick in joysticks:
            joystick.bind(pad=self._update_joystick_output) #bind function to joystick

        from functools import partial
        from kivy.clock import Clock
        Clock.schedule(partial(self.root.update_label, m), .25)
```